# Chop text after a certain symbol appears - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I truncate a string of text after a certain symbol appears, such as the # sign? For instance, I want to change this:

1234 Ocean Drive #PH 2

to:

1234 Ocean Drive

I've discovered that the apartment number in an address which is always indicated by the pound sign can confuse the geocoder, so I'd like to remove all text that appears after a pound sign in the `self.address` when telling the geocoder gem what address to use in the following situation:

property.rb

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base

geocoded_by :full_address

def full_address
"#{self.address}, #{self.city}, #{self.state} #{self.zip}"
end
```

(don't get confused by the pound signs in the above code, I don't mean them, I mean the pound signs that appear in the text string that is `self.address`

Comment: Either use a regex or just chop after the index of the "confusing" character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str = "1234 Ocean Drive #PH 2"
str.split('#')[0]
str.slice(0..(s.index('#')-1))
str.slice(/.*#/).chop()
str[/[^#]+/]
```

Comment: looks like the first one is fastest https://gist.github.com/stim371/5580318 but you may also want to run `chomp` on the resulting string to drop the trailing space.

Comment: excellent, thanks very much for that, I've added `.rstrip` onto the end to get rid of the trailing white space like this: `str.split('#')[0].rstrip`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic working regex for your example string: `(^.*)#.*$`

Something like this would get you the first half:

```
address = 1234 Ocean Drive #PH 2
truncatedaddress = address.match(/(^.*)#.*/i).captures
```

Put this in your self.address method, and remember to handle cutting off any trailing spaces.